# C# Excel Addin - Get the active excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

I am writing an excel Add which will fetch data from database. I am able to add the custom menu to excel in `OnConnection Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2`, but after that the Excel Object is destroyed and I am not able to access the Active Workbook.

How to access the excel workbook that is active?

Answer (score 3):

1>`((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application").ActiveWorkBook`
2>You can check my answer here to get handle to excel application object [Get the excel cell address from a UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708030/get-the-excel-cell-address-from-a-udf/8708200#8708200)