# Event when active Workbook changes

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm writing an *Excel AddIn*. It uses a *Ribbon* where some *Controls* are enabled/disabled depending on the properties of the Workbook.

To do it I guess I should update the state of the Ribbon controls whenever the active *Workbook* changes.

*Chip Pearson's site* explains [how to do it in *VBA*](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738314/c-sharp-excel-addin-get-the-active-excel-workbook) is explained how to get the active Excel Workbook, however I'm not able to trigger this event in my C# *AddIn*.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168477(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Adding following code to `ThisAddIn` *class* the *event* seems to raise up when required.

```
    void Application_ActiveWorkbookChanges(Excel.Workbook Wb)
    {
        // TODO: Active Workbook has changed. Ribbon should be updated.    
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.WorkbookActivate   += 
            new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookActivateEventHandler
                (Application_ActiveWorkbookChanges);
        this.Application.WorkbookDeactivate += 
            new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookDeactivateEventHandler
                (Application_ActiveWorkbookChanges);
    }
```

Comment: Solution is based on the [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168477(v=office.11).aspx) proposed by @TimWilliams and [this early question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180318/c-sharp-using-the-event-handler-workbookopen).

Comment: ¿Is this solution enought effective? ¿Is there any potential problem?