# Programatically create Excel instance and load all add-ins

Tags: .net, excel, interop, marshalling, unmanaged

I am creating an instance of Microsoft Excel in a .NET application (WPF if it matters) and I am embedding it inside like this :

```
        var excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
        var excelObj = Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);
        excelType.InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, excelObj, new object[] { true }, ComCulture);
        var excelHwnd = new IntPtr((int)excelType.InvokeMember("Hwnd", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, excelObj, new object[0], ComCulture));
        var managedWindowHwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
        SetParent(excelHwnd, managedWindowHwnd);
        MoveWindow(excelHwnd, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(Width), Convert.ToInt32(Height), true);
```

All works except Excel does not load the add-ins installed. If I run Excel via the start menu it loads the add-ins.

**I guess I need to specify some arguments to Excel to enable the add-ins loading. But I have no idea what/how...**

Comment: Why don't you just start a process?

Comment: Well we have a large app built around activating and embedding Excel like this and it would be difficult to change things. Starting a process helps load the addins but even so some addins crash on certain commands. I am hoping for a sqitch or some startup option that I can force into Excel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may do this manually using interop, you may refer to my post at [Get the excel cell address from a UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708030/get-the-excel-cell-address-from-a-udf/8708200#8708200) to get handle to excel's Application object. Once you have application you can manually enable addins by looping through application.AddIns and and application.ComAddIns and seting installed/connect property to true for each item